# Customize datepicker CSS to cross out disabled dates

Tags: html, css, datepicker

I have a `datepicker`, whose CSS I have customized according to my needs. I want to put a cross (X) over the disabled dates.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

**Customized CSS**

```
.ui-datepicker {     
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
    display: none;
    height:210px;
    width:195px;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-header {
    position: relative;
    padding: .2em 0;
    font-size:9pt;
    background-color:#BFDBFF;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;  
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.8em;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev-hover,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next-hover {
    top: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span,
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
    margin: 0 4em;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#BFDBFF;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title select {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 1px 0;
}
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month,
.ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year {
    width: 45%;
}
.ui-datepicker table {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 9pt;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 20px 0 .4em;
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
}
.ui-datepicker th {
    padding: .7em .3em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 1px;
}
.ui-datepicker td span,
.ui-datepicker td a {
    display: block;
    padding: .2em;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane {
    background-image: none;
    margin: .7em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 .2em;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button {
    float: right;
    margin: .5em .2em .4em;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em .6em;
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
}
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-buttonpane button.ui-datepicker-current {
    float: left;
}
```

**CSS for crossing out dates**

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td.ui-datepicker-unselectable>span.ui-state-default:before{
    bottom: 0;
    content: "X";
    height: 4px;
    left: 7px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 4px;
}
```

But with this CSS, the dates are not getting crossed out neatly. It looks like:

[image: DatePicker]

I want the 'crosses' to be covering the overall `span` and not just the date and it should look clean. How to achieve this with CSS only?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m75jrys6/) for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have used text-decoration instead of crossing css, remove css of cross out and add this. Hope this will help you...

.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td.ui-datepicker-unselectable>span.ui-state-default
{

```
text-decoration: line-through;
```

}

Comment: .ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td.ui-datepicker-unselectable>span.ui-state-default:before{
    bottom: 0;
    content: "XX";
    height: 4px;
    left: 13px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 4px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td.ui-datepicker-unselectable>span.ui-state-default
{
        text-align: center;
    
}

Will this help.....